# The public type Dog must be defined in its own file

Tags: java, class, public

For some reason I keep getting an error saying

> The public type Dog must be defined in its own file

when I try to compile. Does anyone here know how I can fix it?. Anyone know what I did wrong? I tried looking at some other answers but it said some weird mumbo jumbo about importing something.

Comment: Don't tell me that you didn't name the file `Dog.java`.

Answer (score 3):

If your file name and public class name differs then you get this type of error.

From the error *The public type Dog must be defined in its own file* I am pretty sure that your file name is not `Dog.java`

Answer (score 1):

Move the code for the `Dog` class to a file called `Dog.java`
All top-level classes e.g. the `public Dog class` you want to call from another class must exist in their own specially named files.

Comment: The restriction is on the top-level class, not public classes. You can have multiple public classes if they're nested.

Comment: So edit yours to be correct and/or mine to be more accessible to a newbie. Simple answers are fine, but not if simplifying makes them incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

[Each Java compilation unit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.3) (a `.java` file in all common systems) must contain exactly one *top-level type* (class, enum, or interface) whose [simple name exactly matches the name of the file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6) without the `.java` extension.

It doesn't matter what the access modifier on the class is (public or default), and public nested classes can be placed inside the top-level type, but the single top-level type must match the file name.

(This requirement is technically optional at the discretion of the compiler implementer, but I don't know of any compilers that don't enforce it, and code should always assume the compiler will.)

Comment: You can have multiple top-level types in the same file as long as only one of them is `public` (the others must have package visibility) and the public type's name is the same as the file name.  I do that all the time (only for convenience when I'm experimenting, not in production code).  Maybe that's compiler-dependent, but I got the one from Oracle.

Comment: @ajb Only if the other top-level class is effectively private (it can't be referred to from outside the file, even in the same package).

Comment: I've only tried this for "experiments" that are all contained in just one `.java` file, so I wasn't aware of the effect on other cases.  Thanks for the clarification.